# Rank of the connected components

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Let $G$ be a simple graph with adjacency matrix $A(G)$. Let $v$ be a cut-vertex of $G$. Let $G_1, G_2,\dots, G_k$ be the connected components of the induced graph $G-v$ ( the subgraph resulting after the removal of $v$ and its incident edges from $G$).  Assume that the rank of $A(G_1)$, denote by $r(G_1)$ satisfies $r(G_1+v)=r(G_1)+2.$ Then  prove the following :
$$r(G)=\sum_{i=1}^kr(G_i)+2=r(G-v)+2.$$
This is given in Theorem 2.3 ([here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379511004897)), but I am not getting the proof.
I am not able to understand the following. Assume that there are only 2 connected components in $G-v$, let these are $G_1, G_2$. Then 
$$A(G)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & A(v,G_1) & A(v,G_2) \\ A(v,G_1)^T & A(G_1) & O \\ A(v,G_2)^T & O & A(G_2)\end{bmatrix}.$$ I understood that under given hypothesis, the vector $[0 \ A(v,G_1)]$ is independent of relevant vectors in the matrix $[A(v,G_1)^T \ A(G_1)]$. But how does this lead to  that the first row of $A(G)$ is also independent of the relevant rows of the matrix $[A(v,G_2)^T \ O \ A(G_2)]$.

Comment: By "prove the following" do you imply that you know it is true?
Also it seems quite unlikely that a relation between $r(G_1+v)$ and $r(G_1)$ would directly translate to $r(G)$ and $r(G-v)$ with no assumption on the ranks of other components.

Comment: This is, in fact, true, as per the Theorem 2.3 in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379511004897 but I am confused about the proof.

Comment: This should be mentioned in your question then.

Comment: I have mentioned it now.

Comment: A remark:  in order to have a dependence, you would need to have column vectors $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ so that $A(v, G_1)^T\xi_1 + A(v, G_2)^T\xi_2 = 0$, $A(G_1)\xi_1 = A(v, G_1)$, and $A(G_2)\xi_2 = A(v, G_2)$.  This implies that $\xi_1^T A(G_1)^T\xi_1 + \xi_2^T A(G_2)^T\xi_2 = 0$.  I don't see why these equalities together can't happen, but it might be another way of looking at it.

Comment: I have edited my answer to take your last edit into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof given in the article that you mention relies on the fact that when you stack a row vector $X$ at the top of a matrix $M$, the rank increases by at most $1$ and does so if and only if $X$ is linearly independent of the rows of $M$. The same goes for column vectors stuck to the left (or anywhere) of $M$.

Hence if you have an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ and a submatrix $N$ of size $(n-1)\times (n-1)$, the rank of $M$ is at most $\operatorname{rk}(N)+2$ and this bound is achieved if and only if the $1\times (n-1)$ row and the $n\times 1$ column that you successively added to $N$ are independent of the relevant sets of rows and columns.

Besides this, they use the rank-nullity theorem and I can't see any other tricky points.

**UPDATE**

> how does this lead to  that the first row of $A(G)$ is also independent of the relevant rows of the matrix $[A(v,G_2)^T \ O \ A(G_2)]$.

That is because of the zeroes underneath $A(G_1)$, any writing of $A(v,G)$ as a linear combination of the other rows of $A(G)$ would give you in particular $A(v,G_1)$ as a linear combination of the rows of $A(G_1)$. There is nothing here.

Comment: That I know, but the question is how the 1×(n−1) row and the n×1 column that you successively added to N are independent of the relevant sets of rows and columns, in this particular case.

Comment: That's because the hypothesis regarding nullities in their theorem, together with the rank-nullity, give you the condition you need $\operatorname{rk}(M)=\operatorname{rk}(N)+2$.

Comment: I have still some doubts. Please see I have mentioned my doubt on the question now.